# Custom color for plotly python radar chart labels

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, radar-chart

I want to colorize each label_column with label_color using fig.update_polars(angularaxis_color=color) or fig.update_polars(angularaxis=dict(color=color)) but I can't.

How can I color each column_label the same color as the label_color? I want aa to be written in pink, bb in blue, cc in pink and dd in blue.

```
color_palette = {'Target': 'red', 'Current': 'blue'}


fig = px.line_polar(answers_avg, 
                    r = 'value',
                    theta = 'label_column', 
                    line_close = True, 
                    line_dash = 'group')


for group, color in color_palette.items():
    fig.update_traces(
        line=dict(color=color),
        selector=dict(name=group))
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think individual colors can be changed. If you want to change from the default values, the following code can be used. `fig.update_layout(polar = dict(angularaxis=dict(color='pink')))`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just update the color of the axis label via `fig.layout.polar.angularaxis.color`. But this changes the color of all axis labels for that trace so if you want to have two different colors then you'll have to plot your chart using two different traces each specifying their axis label color.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

color_palette = {'Target': 'red', 'Current': 'blue'}
answers_avg = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(label_column='aa', label_color='pink', group='Current', value=3.),
    dict(label_column='aa', label_color='pink', group='Target', value=4.538462),
    dict(label_column='bb', label_color='blue', group='Current', value=2.818182),
    dict(label_column='bb', label_color='blue', group='Target', value=4.5),
    dict(label_column='cc', label_color='pink', group='Current', value=3.230769),
    dict(label_column='cc', label_color='pink', group='Target', value=4.25),
    dict(label_column='dd', label_color='blue', group='Current', value=2.923077),
    dict(label_column='dd', label_color='blue', group='Target', value=4.583333),
])

fig = px.line_polar(answers_avg, 
                    r = 'value',
                    theta = 'label_column', 
                    line_close = True, 
                    line_dash = 'group')


for group, color in color_palette.items():
    fig.update_traces(
        line=dict(color=color),
        selector=dict(name=group))
    
fig.layout.polar.angularaxis.color = 'blue'    
fig.show()
```

[image]